# Angular 5 watch for assets changes in parent directory

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli, ngx-translate

I have translations `*.json` (I use `ngx-translate`) outside of `src` folder so they're not watched for changes by default. I have a requirement for them to be outside for BE part of the `app`.

Here's the directories structure

```
Project/
├── ClientApp/
│   ├── src/
│   │    └── app/
│   └── .angular-cli.json
│
└── wwwroot/
    └── assets/
          └── i18n/
                ├── en.json
                ├── ...
                └── zh.json
```

how can I tell angular to watch changes in `assets/i18n` folder?
I tried to specify relative directory based on root and .angular-cli.json location but no success so far.

Is this possible?

```
{
    "apps": [{
            "root": "src",
            "assets": [
                {
                    "glob": "*.json",
                    "input": "../../wwwroot/assets/i18nMenu"
                }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as per this thread this functionality is not working in latest cli for angular 5

> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8783